# Read Quandl API errors in Python

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am still relatively new to python, and I am trying to read/catch/handle errors when using the Quandl api.

For example, if I type in a dataset that does not exist, I would like to "read" the error returned from the call, but as a newbie to python, I am not sure how to read the errors.  The API document  [Quandl API](https://www.quandl.com/docs/api#error-codes) shows HTTP errors and Quandl errors that I would like to be able to handle.

Here is a simple code sample that fails, and I am trying to read/catch/handle the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl as Q

df = Q.get("CME/PLZ2016")
```

The Traceback gives lots of details about the error and then has this section at the end:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "D:\PyProj\Quandl\WorkingSampleQuandlDownload.py", line 7, in <module>  
     df = Q.get(exchsymbol, trim_start=strstartdate)  
  File "D:\Python33\lib\Quandl\Quandl.py", line 124, in get  
    raise DatasetNotFound(error)  
Quandl.Quandl.DatasetNotFound: Dataset not found. Check Quandl code: CME/PLZ2016 for errors
```

If I use the try/exception, I get:
Dataset not found. Check Quandl code: CME/PLZ2016 for errors

So, I would like to ask for your assistance in teaching me how to read/catch/handle the above error from Quandl.  Hopefully I can learn how to find out the Quandl error and the HTTP status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the NotFoundError from Quandl:

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl as Q
from quandl.errors.quandl_error import NotFoundError 

try:
  df = Q.get("CME/PLZ2016")
except NotFoundError:
  print(NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the error first:

```
import Quandl as Q
from Quandl.Quandl import DatasetNotFound

try:
    df = Q.get("CME/PLZ2016")
except DatasetNotFound:
    # put your response code here
```